# getting form data from POST using express.js with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

so i built a chatroom and everything worked fine up until i changed the system over to use just uid heres a little rundown of how it works

when the user signs up he gets assigned a uid thats put in the data base along with his credentials so everytime the user logs in it asks the server to get the uid thats associated with the username you typed in on the text box and sets it as a cookie like this

`setCookies()` gets called on submit

```
function setCookies() {
    var username = document.getElementById("login-username").value
    console.log(username)
    getLoggedInUserInfo(username)
}
function getLoggedInUserInfo(username){     
console.log(username)
socket.emit('getLoggedInUserInfo',username)
}
socket.on('loggedInUserInfo',function(uid){
    document.cookie = "uid=" + uid;
})
```

but this is a problem on the signup page because the user doesnt have anything about him on the database yet

so what i was thinking what if i could set the cookie on the server side using express but i cant get any values from the form using express like this

```
app.post('/apolloLogin', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/apolloMainchat', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/apolloLogin', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
},function(req, res){
   var username = res.query.username

    console.log("tettestset")
    //res.cookie('cookieName','randomUid', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
}),
```

**Here i would get the uid associated with the username**
**And then set the uid cookie like this**

`res.cookie('cookieName','randomUid', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });`

but i always get null for the username value and it says res.cookie is not a function

what am i doing wrong here with express

**EDIT**

now i am trying this

```
app.post('/apolloSignup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/apolloMainchat', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/apolloSignup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
},function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.username)
}));
```

**SECOND EDIT**

this is what i am using now and i am getting null from the `console.log`

```
app.post('/apolloSignup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {successRedirect: '/apolloMainchat',failureRedirect: '/apolloSignup',failureFlash: true}),function(req, res){
    console.log(req)
});
```

**THIS IS WHAT MY HTML LOOKS LIKET**

```
<html>
    <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/regular.css" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>  
            <script src="scripts/bic_core.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-register-div" id="login-register-div">
                            <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
                            <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
                                <div class="login-error">
                                    <script>
                                        $("#login-username").addClass("textboxError");
                                        $("#login-password").addClass("textboxError");
                                        </script>
                                    <%= message %>
                                </div>
                                <% } %>
                                    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
            <div id="login-container" class="login-container">
                <form action="/apolloSignup" method="post">
                    <center><h1>Sign Up</h1></center>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="login-username" id="login-username" name="username">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="login-password" id="login-password" name="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="login-submit" id="login-submit" onclick="setCookies()">
                    <a class="signup-login-link" href="/apolloLogin">Log In</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
```

Comment: Is `username` a value from the HTML `form`? If so, it will be accessible in the `req.body` value, not `req.query`. `req.query` exposes the values for URL query parameters.

Comment: actually, it looks like you are referencing `res.query.username`. That's not valid  - did you mean `req.query.username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that once you get to `failureRedirect` / `successRedirect`, the request/response cycle has ended, so you won't be hitting the next middleware. However, if you've set up the passport local auth correctly, you should have access to `req.user`, which will contain the logged-in user's username and other info.

Try doing the cookie setting in `/apolloMainchat` route, referencing `req.user`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referencing `res.query.username`. That's not valid - did you mean `req.query.username`? The query parameters will be on the request object, not the response object.

Additionally, if you are getting POST data from an HTML form, the values should be accessible through `req.body` rather than `req.query`.

Comment: i have tried doing console.log(req.body.username) with no success

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include what your HTML form looks like?